# The existence or lack of answers which are "Not an answer"

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

A long-standing user with the Marshal badge thinks that a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170803/will-a-modern-processor-like-the-i7-follow-pointers-and-prefetch-their-data-wh/76775728#76775728) which "does not seem to have *anything* to do with the question" (emphasis added) does not qualify as "Not an answer" because it answers *a* question. He goes on to explain that this flag is reserved exclusively for posts which are not answers in a strict semantic sense, such as questions. As evidence of this he cites the [official guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553) on what to flag as "Not an answer". This guidance includes a list of examples of things which should be flagged:

1. Thanking the poster
2. Asking a new question
3. Bumping the question
4. Linking to an answer

These examples do in fact all fall into the stated category. However, the post begins with the statement "You flag as NAA things posted as answers that clearly and obviously do not attempt to answer an on-topic question or the question asked." The inclusion of the category "on-topic question" as well as the phrasing of "question *asked*" (emphasis added) would seem to indicate that relevance is relevant. One might argue that "on-topic question" is in reference to the question being on topic for the *site*; however, the list of examples of things which should *not* be flagged includes "answers to off-topic questions". So this can't be what the guidance is telling us to flag when it tells us to flag posts which are not an answer to an on-topic question.

Furthermore, and this of course isn't dispositive, the list of examples of things not to flag doesn't include answers that are completely irrelevant to the question, but rather consists of

1. Wrong answers
2. Answers that use a different programming language
3. Answers to off-topic questions

So are completely off-topic posts which are answers to something "Not an answer", or is the flag in fact reserved exclusively for posts which are not an answer to anything?

Comment: [Marshal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732): *"Raise 500 flags deemed helpful by moderators or the system"*

Comment: You tagged it as a support question, but I am unsure what kind of support you seek. I will close this question for the time being. Please edit it to clearly state the problem you require support with, or alternatively, if this was meant to be a discussion topic, please rewrite it in the form of a question seeking input from the community.

Comment: The guidance says "an on-topic question *or* the question asked". Either suffices.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, but you seem to have missed the part where his objection was "This does not seem to have anything to do with the question."

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn I have not, yet that comment wasn't made with regard to the NAA policy. It is a reason to downvote and they probably stated it with regard to that. It is not a reason to NAA flag, since the answer is still the result of an "attempt to answer an on-topic question".

Comment: @MisterMiyagi An on topic question, by definition, has *something* to do with the question. He said it was completely unrelated.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Did you edit your comment to add the "made with regard to" stuff or did I just fail to see that on the first read?

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn I think you are misreading. The *hypothetical* question to which the answers fits must be on-topic. For that it doesn't matter what the *current* question is; a question's on-topicness is not defined by other questions.

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn Yes, though it doesn't change the point I was making.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're obviously correct that his "comment wasn't made with regard to the NAA policy(, but) probably ... with regard to (down voting)", to the extent that that sentence makes sense, given that he explicitly states such - again to the extent that that sentence makes sense. However I don't see how that's relevant. I mean he obviously disagrees with me, but what's your point?

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn I'm not sure what *your* point is. You brought up that quote as, I guess, an objection to me pointing out part the wording of the NAA description. Since the quote was not made with regard to NAA, I don't see how it applies by itself nor how your follow-up comment on on-topicness would clear that up.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I just want to state for posterity (as I also said explicitly in the comments to that post prior to this meta post) that I never said he shouldn't down vote my answer.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This is a response to the comment starting "I think you are misreading. The *hypothetical* ..." I think you're missing something. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that "on topic question" from the portion of the guidance stating "You flag as NAA things (that) do not attempt to answer an on-topic question or the question asked." is talking about *site* on topic ness. However the list of examples of things you are *not* supposed to use this flag with includes answers to questions which are off topic. So that can't be what that's saying to use the flag for.

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn The guidance for not flagging NAA *posted on* off-topic questions is explicitly to avoid wasting flags, since these are limited per person per day. That doesn’t mean that NAA would be wrong there, just not economical. Note that this is yet another case from an answer *applying to* an off-topic question but *posted on* an on-topic question.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi In response to your penultimate comment. Yes, I agree, what he was saying does not constitute an assertion of my interpretation of "on topic question" over yours. That's not what I meant. I originally thought you had the same interpretation of "on topic question" I did, namely that "on topic" is in reference to the post rather than the site, which is why I observed that the said "This does not seem to have anything to do with the question."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Fair enough

Comment: *"thinks that a post which "does not seem to have anything to do with the question" (emphasis added) does not qualify as "Not an answer" because it answers a question"* - yeah that's one for the ages. As long as I have visited this site, that comes up as a discussion point / hot debate / tug o' war. There have also been motions to just get rid of NAA and VLQ entirely for being universally misunderstood. Or abused to not have to downvote and take that -1 reputation investment, of course.

Answer (score 19):

GSerg is correct, your answer does not qualify for an "NAA" flag.

It is, however, a *very* late answer to an *old* question. On top of that, a lot of your answer's content is actually hidden in the plethora of links you've added.

Links should only be used as *additional* information in answers. Accessing the links shouldn't be a requirement for the answer to be complete.

So, what GSerg did there (downvote and *not* flag it as NAA), was entirely within SO's rules and guidelines.

Comment: This is not an answer. It consists exclusively of a pure assertion without explanation followed by irrelevant observations/claims.

Comment: GSerg said that the reason he down voted it was that it "does not seem to have anything to do with the question". Furthermore I would like to add that I clarified in my discussion with him in the comments that I was not saying he should flag as an alternative to down voting, but rather in addition to it.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it your assertion is in fact an answer to this question. My apologies. I shouldn't have flagged it as "Not an answer".

Comment: @Cerbrus I will however point out that "It is, however, a very late answer to an old question. On top of that, a lot of your answer's content is actually hidden in the plethora of links you've added. Links should only be used as additional information in answers. Accessing the links shouldn't be a requirement for the answer to be complete." is completely irrelevant to the question and the person who prompted the question never said any of that.

Comment: @M.J.Rayburn I'm just listing a few possible reasons for the downvote(s)...